# Is there any OpenCMS community?

Tags: opencms

I started devoeloping webs in OpenCMS and I found out few problems.
I looked for some comunity IRC/slack/discord/etc. , but i didnt find anything.
Dont someone know, if there isnt some comunication channel (official or unoficial) used by openCMS community or developers?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.opencms.org/en/development/mailinglist.html

Answer (score 0):

The 'official' communication channel is the mailing list: http://www.opencms.org/en/development/mailinglist.html.

There is also a pretty silent Gitter channel:
https://gitter.im/opencms-community/general